# Sourcetree でのクローン時、改行コードが自動で CRLF に変換されないよう設定する方法は？

Tags: git, sourcetree

Sourcetree でクローンすると、改行コードがLFだったものが自動的にCRLFに変換されてしまうのですが、どこで設定できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 生の git コマンドは利用可能ですか？ 直で clone を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: `git` `mercurial` の設定によっては commit/checkout の際に改行コードの自動変換を行うことができ、今はそれが有効なのでしょう。では設定をどこですればよいかは、運用方針によって異なります。とりあえず `git config` で `core.autocrlf` を設定しましょう。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/37775 マルチポスト

Answer (score 5):

コマンドラインで

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

とするか、

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

としてみましょう。設定ファイルをいじるなら`C:\Users\ユーザ名\.gitconfig`ファイルの

```
autocrlf = true
```

の所を`input`か`false`に変えても直ると思います。

---

**Inputとfalse、trueの違い**
`true`は、チェックアウトするときは`LF`を`CRLF`に変換します。コミットする時は`CRLF`を`LF`に変換します。

`input`は、チェックアウトするときには変換しませんがコミットする時は`CRLF`を`LF`に変換します。

`false`は変換しません。

チェックアウトのところはクローンしても同じです。