# Windows版GitHub Desktopで改行コードを変換したくない

Tags: windows, git, github-desktop

Windows版GitHub Desktopを使っています。

1. 改行コードを変換しない設定はありますでしょうか？
2. 変わってしまった改行コードを戻すことは出来ますでしょうか？
   (出来ないというような記事ばかりで諦めかけています・・)

Comment: 重複候補 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/26663

Comment: ちなみに Git for Windows は入っているのでしょうか？

Comment: "変わってしまった改行コード" という事象を具体的に説明することは可能でしょうか(何を見て(何と何を比較して)"変わってしまった"と認識しているのか)。

Comment: LFへの統一という違う方向の記事が多いですが、これらを参考にCRLFへの統一に応用してみるとか。[git repository 中の CRLF を LF に一括変換する](https://kokufu.blogspot.com/2017/03/git-repository-crlf-lf.html), [気をつけて！Git for Windowsにおける改行コード](https://qiita.com/uggds/items/00a1974ec4f115616580), [GitHub で Download ZIP した時に改行コードが LF になってしまう件(原因は core.autocrlf)](https://stakiran.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/11/14/193053)

Answer (score 1):

### 改行コードを変換しない設定

あります。`core.autocrlf` を設定すれば良いです。

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

この設定値には `true` / `input` / `false` が指定できます。

参考：[8.1 Git のカスタマイズ - Git の設定](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)（下の方に `core.autocrlf` の説明があります）

### 変わってしまった改行コードを戻す方法

どの時点で改行コードが変わってしまったのかによります。

`git clone` の時点で変わってしまったのであれば、設定を変えた後一度すべて削除して再度 `git clone` すれば良いです。

コミットの時点で変わってしまったのであれば、設定を変えた後そのコミットを `git revert` 等で巻き戻せば良さそうです。

Comment: Windows環境の辛いところは、各ツールがどこにインストールされたgit.exeを使用するかバラバラでして。そしてgit.exe毎にそれぞれ固有のglobal configを持ちます…。

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[Git for Windows の設定ファイルの場所](https://qiita.com/masmatsum/items/da780bed0472bfd74fa8), [\[Windows\]gitの設定ファイルと最初の設定(ファイル名文字化け対策と個人識別情報)](https://zero-config.com/windows/git-config.html) GitHub と Atlassian と 更に他のベンダ それぞれで違っていてもおかしくないですが、同じ開発元のツールで変わっていたりするものでしょうか？

Comment: @kunif どういう意味でしょうか？　sayuri さんのコメントは、git.exe で設定を変更する方法が分かっても、GitHub Desktop がどの git.exe を使っているかが分からないのでそこまで書いてあった方がより親切だ、という意図だと思うのですが。

Comment: 断言されている感じだったので、明確に違うものが使われているのかと知りたかったのですが。つまりgit.exeはバラバラにいっぱいあるようですが、聞きたいのはglobal configの設定場所が1か所なのか、exeに応じてバラバラなのか、というところですね。

Comment: @kunif たとえば考えられるシナリオのひとつとして、Cygwin の git も併用されている場合だと「あれ？　ちゃんと設定したはずなんだけどな……」というのが起こりえます。他にも Git for Windows の外にインストールされた msys2 の git や、WSL Ubuntu の git など……。このあたりはちゃんと回答に書くべきなのですが、まだ私の手が回っていません。

Comment: なるほど、その辺の独自世界を築いていそうなものを失念していました。

Comment: revert時に変わってしまったようでして、(autocrlf = false後に)resetしても、戻らないようです。 revertには、autocrlf = falseは効かないようです (怖い)