# SourceTreeでクローンしたファイルをVisualStudio2013 で確認すると改行コード不一致で変更とされる

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, sourcetree

環境移行にともない新PCにGit、SourceTree、VisualStudioをインストールし
リポジトリからクローンをしたところ、タイトルの事象が起きました。
旧環境では発生していません。

旧環境
　Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
　Git 2.6.1.windows.1
　SourceTree 1.9.5.0
　VisualStudio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
新環境
　Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
　Git 2.6.3.windows.1
　SourceTree 3.4.7
　VisualStudio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 REL

新環境にてSourceTreeでクローンしたものをVisualStudioのチームエクスプローラーで確認したところ
全てのファイルが変更対象となっており、「未変更のものと比較」したところ一見変更されていない(差分が表示されない)が
HEADの改行コードがLF、ローカルの改行コードがCRLFとなっていました。

旧環境で同様の操作を行った際は変更対象とならず、
テキストエディタで確認したローカルのファイルの改行コードはCRLFとなっているので
HEADもローカルもCRLFとして比較していると思われます。

新環境でも旧環境と同じようにHEADもCRLFとして比較したいのですが・・・

また、調査の中でクローンを作成する際に新環境のVisualStudioでのみLFで作成されるということが確認できました。
　旧環境のSourceTreeにて既存リポジトリを新規フォルダにクローンする
　　→CRLFで作成される
　旧環境のVisualStudioのチームエクスプローラー→接続→ローカルGitリポジトリの「複製」で
　既存リポジトリを新規フォルダに複製する
　　→CRLFで作成される
　新環境のSourceTreeにて既存リポジトリを新規フォルダにクローンする
　　→CRLFで作成される
　新環境のVisualStudioのチームエクスプローラー→接続→ローカルGitリポジトリの「複製」で
　既存リポジトリを新規フォルダに複製する
　　→**LFで作成される**
※すべて同一の既存リポジトリを対象にクローン(複製)しています)
※サーバー上のファイルがどちらの改行コードで保存されているかは不明ですが、
　新環境でgit configで確認できるcore.autocrlfはすべてfalseの状態なのでCRLFで保存されている？

おそらくVisualStudioのチームエクスプローラーがgitコマンド(?)を実行する際の
設定などが新旧で異なっているのが原因と思うのですが、その設定をどこで確認/変更できるのか分からずpostさせていただきました。

Comment: 重複候補: [Sourcetree でのクローン時、改行コードが自動で CRLF に変換されないよう設定する方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/26663)

Comment: http://ogawa.s18.xrea.com/tdiary/20200828p01.html `~/.gitconfig は見ておらず Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\gitconfig の設定に従っているようだった。` バージョン違いですが参考になれば。

Answer (score 3):

gitの設定ファイルは３ヶ所に置かれ、優先順位の高い順に次のようになります。

- `--local`; `.git/config`
- `--global`; `~/.gitconfig`
- `--system`; `/etc/gitconfig`

このうち、`--local`はcloneの時点では存在しないので、`--global`か`--system`のどちらかの設定を見ていることになります。`--global`に設定されている場合はいいのですが、そうでない場合は`--system`を参照することになります。
UNIX系OSではあまり問題にならないのですが、Windowsには`/etc`がそもそも存在せず、各gitはそれぞれの独自の場所を参照することになります。

SourceTreeとVisual Studioで挙動が異なるということは、SourceTreeとVisual Studioが使用するgitが異なり、参照する`--system`設定も異なってきていることが原因と思われます。
具体的には[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)を使えばどのファイルにアクセスしたか追跡できます。手元のVisual Studioでは、`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\gitconfig`と`C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig`との両方にアクセスしていました。しかしSourceTreeは前者にアクセスすることはないと思われます。

ともあれ難しく考えることはなく、

```
git config --global core.autocrlf <設定したい値>
```

と実行すれば、`--global`に設定を保存でき、どのgitから起動しても同じ結果が得られるようになります。

---

> 新環境でgit configで確認できるcore.autocrlfはすべてfalseの状態なので

念のため、あくまでgit configで起動されたgitコマンドから見た結果でしかなく、SourceTreeやVisual Studioが（特に`--system`設定に関して）同じ設定を見ているわけではない点に気をつけてください。